# Code Bulkification Problem

Tags: trigger, map, bulkification

I have a requirement to bulkify the code. The trigger is present on Case Object and I have to take the  CaseTeamTemplate Id's whose names match with the CaseTeamTemplate objects.
I have written this code outside the for loop.

```
List <Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, case_language__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN : trigger.newMap.keySet()];

Map<Id, CaseTeamTemplate > mapCaseTeamTemplate = new  Map<Id, CaseTeamTemplate >

([Select id from CaseTeamTemplate where name In (select case_language__c from case where Id in : trigger.newMap.keySet() )  ]);

for(Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
{
   //CaseTeamTemplate  obj = mapCaseTeamTemplate.get(caseObj.Id);
}
```

I am getting Compile Error: semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'case_language__c'

I am not able to fix the issue without calling it within for loop. Please suggest how can this be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
Set<String> templateNames = new Set<string>();

for(Case case : triger.new){
    templateNames.add(case.case_language__c);
}

CaseTeamTemplate[] caseTeamTemplates = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                        FROM CaseTeamTemplate
                                        WHERE Name IN : templateNames];

Map<String, Id> cttNameToIdMap = Map<String, Id>();

for(CaseTeamTemplate ctt : caseTeamTemplates){
    cttNameToIdMap.put(ctt.Name, ctt.Id);
}
```